# how to scrape next page in this website https://palagems.myshopify.com/collections/all-gems?page=1&view=grid

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i want to scrape all pages in this website

my code

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
import pandas as pd
import urllib.request
import urllib
url = 'https://palagems.myshopify.com/collections/all-gems'

while True:
    session = requests.Session()
    session.headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36"}


    content = session.get(url, verify=False).content

    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")

    posts = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'grid-item small--one-half medium--one-quarter large--one-quarter'})

    npo_jobs = {}
    i = 1
    items = []  
    data = []
    for url in posts:



        #price = url.find('span').text
        link = url.find('a').get('href')
        links = ('https://palagems.myshopify.com'+ link)
        url_response = requests.get(links)
        url_data = url_response.text
        url_soup = BeautifulSoup(url_data, 'html.parser')
        title_find = url_soup.find('div',{'class':'grid-item large--two-fifths'})
        title = title_find.find('h1').text
        img_find = url_soup.find('div',{'class':'lazyload__image-wrapper no-js product__image-wrapper'})
        img = img_find.find('img')
        filename = img.get('alt')
        img_link = img.get('src')
        image = ('https:'+ img_link)

        #print(image)
        #for imgs in img_find:
            #print 
        #title_info = url_soup.find('div',{'class':'DetailRow'})
        #title = title_info.find('h1').text
        #price_info = url_soup.find('div',{'class':'DetailRow PriceRow p-price'})
        #price = price_info.find('span').text
        #print(title)
        #print(price)
        #print(links)
        #for tr in url_soup.find_all('tr'):

        desciption = url_soup.find('div',{'class':'product-description rte'})
        planet_data = dict()
        planet_data['gem-color'] = desciption.find('p',{'class':'gem-color'}).text
        planet_data['gem-shape'] = desciption.find('p',{'class':'gem-shape'}).text
        planet_data['gem-measurements'] = desciption.find('p',{'class':'gem-measurements'}).text

        planet_data['gem-country'] = desciption.find('p',{'class':'gem-country'})

        planet_data['gem-enhancement'] = desciption.find('p',{'class':'gem-enhancement'})
        planet_data['gem-qty-of-stones'] = desciption.find('p',{'class':'gem-qty-of-stones'}).text
        planet_data['gem-total-weight'] = desciption.find('p',{'class':'gem-total-weight'}).text
        #print(planet_data)
        data.append((title,planet_data, links ))
        imagefile = open(filename +".jpeg",'wb')
        imagefile.write(urllib.request.urlopen(image).read())
        imagefile.close()







    #for index, tr in enumerate(desciption.find_all('div',{'class':'rww'})):
        #planet_data = dict()
        #values = [td.text for td in tr.find_all('div',{'class':'rww'})]
        #planet_data['name'] = tr.find('div',{'class':'cll1'}).text
        #planet_data['info'] = tr.find('div',{'class':'cll2'}).text
        #print(planet_data)

        #if index == 0:
            #data.append((title,price,planet_data,link))

        #else:
            #data.append((None,None,planet_data,None))











    #items.append(planet_data)    













    #data.append((title, price, link ))

    #data.extend(data_desciption)   



    #npo_jobs= [title,price,row,link]






#data_new = data +","+ data_desciption
#find_url = soup.find('div',{'class':'text-center'})
#urls = find_url.find('a').get('href')






with open('ineryrg564855.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
 writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
 writer.writerow(['title','gem-color','gem-shape','gem-measurements','gem-country','gem-enhancement','gem-qty-of-stones','gem-total-weight','link'])
 #The for loop
 for title,planet_data,links in data:




    writer.writerow([title,planet_data['gem-color'],planet_data['gem-shape'],planet_data['gem-measurements'],planet_data['gem-country'],planet_data['gem-enhancement'],planet_data['gem-qty-of-stones'],planet_data['gem-total-weight'],links])





#npo_jobs_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(npo_jobs, orient ='index', columns=['title', 'price','row','link'])
#npo_jobs_df.to_csv('npo_jobs.csv')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You've told us what you want to do and shown us some code. What's wrong with that code? _Specifically_, how does it fail to do what you want? Please read [ask].

Comment: I want To scrape all pages in this web site https://palagems.myshopify.com/collections/all-gems?page=1&view=grid

Comment: ...and, again, _specifically_, how does the code you've included here fail to do that? _Again_, please read [ask].

Comment: I tried to edit your code for readability, but removing the spaces and commented out code triggers the "your post is mostly code" error. Like the others, I'd suggest clarifying a specific question, along with the results you're getting vs the results you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

here how i scrape next page in website that not have href class in next url code

```
find_url = soup.find('div',{'class':'text-center'})
urls = find_url.find('a',{'title':'Next »'}).get('href')
url = ('https://palagems.myshopify.com'+ urls )
print(url)
```